# Data from a form is not getting added to the database with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a registration page where the user's username and password would get sent to a database I have set up on Heroku. I do not get any errors and after clicking the submit button I get sent to the "you are registered" page, but the username and password don't get added to the db. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)


# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True


Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
db1 = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db1.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = db1.Column(db1.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    username = db1.Column(db1.String, nullable=False)
    password = db1.Column(db1.String, nullable=False)

    def add_user(self, u):
        self.users.append(u)
        u.user_id = self.id


with app.app_context():
    db1.init_app(app)
    db1.create_all()




@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route("/registered", methods=['POST'])
def registered():
    username = request.form.get('rusername')
    password = request.form.get('rpassword')
    u1 = User(username=username, password=password)
    db1.session.add(u1)
    db1.session.commit()
    return '<h1> You are registered! <h1>'

@app.route("/loggedin", methods=['POST'])
def loggedin():
    return '<h1> You are logged in! <h1>'
```

Thank you for your help!